Problems using sqlite with kotlin in android studio
I am trying to make an app, which have a database with custumers. But the main feature goes with problem:
HERE IS MAIN FILE:
class AddPatientActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_patient)

        val dbPatients = DBHelperPatients(this, null)

        val nameField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.newPatientName)
        val surnameField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.newPatientSurName)
        val fathernameField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.newPatientFatherName)
        val phonenumberField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.newPatientPhoneNumber)
        val birthdayField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.newPatientBirthday)

        val btnConfirm = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnAddPatient)

        btnConfirm.setOnClickListener{
            val name = nameField.text.toString().trim()
            val surname = surnameField.text.toString().trim()
            val fathername = fathernameField.text.toString().trim()
            val phonenumber = phonenumberField.text.toString().trim()
            val birthday = birthdayField.text.toString().trim()

            if(name==""||surname==""||fathername==""||phonenumber==""||birthday==""){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Не все поля заполнены!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            val patient = Patient( name, surname, fathername, birthday, phonenumber, 0)
            Log.w("myapp", "${patient.Name}, ${patient.Surname}, ${patient.FatherName}, ${patient.Birthday}, ${patient.PhoneNumber}, ${patient.Amount}")
            dbPatients.writeToDb(patient)

            Log.w("myapp", "${dbPatients.getFromDb(surname)}")

        }

    }
}

DATABASE CLASS:
class DBHelperPatients(context: Context, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?) :
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, "dbPatients", factory, 1) {

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        val query = ("CREATE TABLE " + "dbPatients" + " ("
                + "id" + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "name" + " TEXT," +
                "surname" + " TEXT," +
                "fathername" + " TEXT," +
                "birthday" + " TEXT," +
                "phonenumber" + " TEXT," +
                "amount" + " TEXT" + ")")
        db!!.execSQL(query)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db!!.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbPatients")
        onCreate(db)
    }

    fun writeToDb(patient: Patient):Boolean{
        val values = ContentValues()

        values.put("name", patient.Name)
        values.put("surname", patient.Surname)
        values.put("fathername", patient.FatherName)
        values.put("birthday", patient.Birthday)
        values.put("phonenumber", patient.PhoneNumber)
        values.put("amount", patient.Amount)

        val db = this.writableDatabase
        println(values)
        if(db.insert("dbPatients", null, values).toInt() == -1){
            db.close()
            return false
        }
        db.close()
        return true
    }

    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    fun getFromDb(surname: String):Boolean{
        val db = readableDatabase
        val result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * dbPatients WHERE Surname = '$surname'", null)
        return result.moveToFirst()
    }

}

CUSTUMER CLASS (Patient)
class Patient(val Name:String, val Surname:String, val FatherName:String, val Birthday:String, val PhoneNumber:String, val Amount:Int) {

}

Everything works fine, but when it calls function "writeToDb" application crashes.
I was doing that code mostly by the youtube quide. I tryed to find solution online, but seems like I'm the only one with that problem

The SELECT statement should be
"SELECT * FROM dbPatients WHERE Surname = '$surname'"

i.e. the FROM keyword has been added.
The Log would have contained something like:-
2024-04-30 06:07:54.297 E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "dbPatients": syntax error
2024-04-30 06:07:54.298 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2024-04-30 06:07:54.299 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: a.a.so78403383kotlinsqlite, PID: 22937
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "dbPatients": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * dbPatients WHERE Surname = 'Andrews'


this taken from running the code copied from the question.

You may wish to consider using the convenience query method instead of the rawQuery method, this builds the underlying SQL from the parameters passed; e.g. you could use:-
fun getFromDb(surname: String): Boolean {
    val db = readableDatabase
    return db.query("dbPatients",null,"Surname=?", arrayOf(surname),null,null,null).moveToFirst()
}


This is also considered safer as the ? is bound (i.e. the ? is replaced by the value via the SQLite call) and thus protects against SQL injection.

